# Making a Powershell form button to install a package using chocolatey

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

```
$InstallBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

$InstallBtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100)

$InstallBtn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,30)

$InstallBtn.Text = "Install"

$main_form.Controls.Add($InstallBtn)



$InstallWinrar={choco install winrar}

$InstallBtn.Add_Click($InstallWinrar)
```

Note: Chocolatey is already installed on my machine but When I am trying to install a package using choco install command through a button in GUI nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working example that creates a form, adds a button to the form and then shows the form. Clicking the button runs Notepad.exe.

```
$CommandToExecute={notepad.exe} # <-- change this to your choco command

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100)


$Btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$Btn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,30)
$Btn.Text = "Open Notepad"
$Btn.Add_Click($CommandToExecute)

$Form.Controls.Add($Btn)

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

You can modify the above to run your choco command. If your unable to execute Choco still, you might need to specify the absolute path

Comment: Notepad is opening but choco command is not working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "you might need to specify the absolute path"?

Comment: By absolute path i mean instead of `choco` you might need to specify the location as well  - e.g. `c:\path\to\choco.exe`. By default it will be installed to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe` - but you need to check your system and confirm where choco.exe is actually installed.